# Validate document against xsd in schema database using java api

Tags: marklogic

I hava a schema in schema database of marklogic.
Is there a way to do strict validation when I insert a document using Java API against the schema in database and throw an error if its not valid.

Any help on how to approach the solution through is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for the Java API is the same as it is [for the REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357781/validate-document-against-xsd-using-rest-api-marklogic). You can install a REST transform.  It can be this simple:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

module namespace trans = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/transform/validate";

declare function trans:transform(
  $context as map:map,
  $params as map:map,
  $content as document-node()
) as document-node()
{
  let $validate := validate strict { $content }
  return $content
};
```

Note: upload this with transform name 'validate', as transform name must match its namespace.

You could also implement this transform using Javascript.  For more see [Writing Transformations](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms#id_63592) in the REST Application Developer's Guide.

Comment: Whats the significance of the namespace http://marklogic.com/rest-api/transform in the above statement here?

Comment: Whats the significance of the namespace marklogic.com/rest-api/transform in the above statement here?

I have a XSD in the schema database with the following namespace:
http://vikram.com/transdata/customertypes

How can I validate the XML document using the transformation I loaded to the database? I am passing the transform = validate to the below command:

curl -X PUT -T developertype.xml -H "Content-type: application/xml" --anyauth --user admin:admin "http://localhost:8061/LATEST/documents?uri=/transdata/developertype.xml&transform=validate

Comment: That namespace is the documented way to create a REST XQuery transformation (see the docs link in my answer).  the url you're using to call your transform looks good.  To troubleshoot your transform, check ErrorLog.txt and use xdmp:log.  Your XSD should be able to have any namespace.  For more on using XSD schemas see: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/loading_schemas

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. The ErrorLog.txt says Status 500: XDMP-VALIDATENODECL: (err:XQDY0084) validate strict { $content } -- Missing element declaration: Expected declaration for node fn:doc("")/root in non-lax mode using schema "". This is the same error I am getting even whether I use Java API or REST API but works when I use XQuery.
It looks like REST API not able to find the schema. In case of XQuery, we import schema "my-schema" at "/schemas/my-schema.xsd"; how do we do it here in case of using a Transformation?

Comment: You can use the same import schema line in your transform to see if that helps. But if the xml file is properly namespaced, and the schema can be found by the rest user that connects to your rest extension, it should work. Perhaps your rest user has no read access to the schema?

Comment: Thanks. It worked after I added the import schema line in my transformation as you suggested.